# How to get the maximum filesize allowed to upload in my php settings with php?

Tags: php, upload

I don't have access to `php.ini` on my host, and I want to get the maximum file size limit for uploads, via php code. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you wanting just to get info on it, or increase the size because you can't edit the `.ini` file to increase it? If so, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2185500/1415724) to modify via `.htaccess`

Comment: First i want to get the info. I'm getting a error when i try to upload a big file. After if this is the issue, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Then if you don't have an `.htaccess` file in your root, create one and follow the answer I gave you above, and upload it in ASCII format. That will work.

Comment: Another thing which may be preventing bigger uploads, could be in your script itself. There are many possibilities. Posting your code could help, if you want me to have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/ini_get) to get the value of [`upload_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) directives::

```
$upload_max_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
$post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
```

For just viewing this value along with other information, you could use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo).

**UPDATE:**
  If you can somehow manage to update the `php.ini` configuration, then update it as follows:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2048M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 2050M
```

The above configuration sets the limits as 2 GB. It might not be a good idea to have such huge file upload limits. If you're doing this on a real website, users with malicious intent could use this to upload random files and you'd then run out of disk space. I suggest you set it to something reasonable and display an error message if the file size is larger than that. This could vary per application and might depend on the use-case though.

See also: [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you. And what is the correct syntax to set this to 2 Giga in php.ini?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: If you don't have access to edit `php.ini` file, then you can try to set it via `.htaccess`. See [Fred's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686087/how-to-get-the-maximum-filesize-allowed-to-upload-in-my-php-settings-with-php/20686115?noredirect=1#comment30978133_20686087) above.

Comment: I don't have access, but I can ask to admin change. post_max_size = 100000000 ? Is only numbers? In bytes?

Comment: See this chart => http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/calculate/ @JoaoPaulo and http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: No, it's in MB. The correct syntax would be: `upload_max_filesize = 2048M` (assuming you're trying to set it to 2GB). See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ini_get()](http://php.net/ini_get) function

Answer (score 0):

As explained, `ini_get`, however you need to check both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` which must be greater.

```
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
```